# Magento 2 remember me (log in)

Tags: magento2, login, persistent

I understand that the built in "remember me" functionality of Magento persists the shopping cart.

However, I want it to **also** keep the customer logged in if they select "Remember me". How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this feature in magento 2 need to overwrite Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost controller and template file

for more details
please follow the link
http://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-add-remember-me-username-and-password-feature-in-magento-2/

The code is available on GitHub at https://github.com/jothibasuj/Remember-Me

Comment: Doesn't this extension save the user's password in a Cookie in clear text?